# ffmpeg: Unable to find a suitable output format, libfaac

Tags: video, ffmpeg, html5-video

I just downloaded "FFmpeg git-070b0e1 32-bit Static (Latest)" from http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/. I extracted the files on my Vista machine and then updated my PATH to point to `presets` and `bin` folders.

The first command I ran was this:

```
ffmpeg -i C:/a.avi  -vcodec libtheora  -qscale 6  -acodec libvorbis  -ab 128k  -vf scale="480:-1"   C:/a.ogv
```

I got this error:

```
Please use -q:a or -q:v, -qscale is ambiguous
[NULL @ 0200F800] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'C:/a.ogv''
C:/a.ogv': Invalid argument
```

The second command I ran was this:

```
ffmpeg -i C:/a.avi  -vcodec libx264  -preset slow  -profile main  -crf 20  -acodec libfaac  -ab 128k  -vf scale="480:-1"   C:/a.mp4
```

I got this error: `Unknown encoder 'libfaac'`

**Questions:**

1. I'm trying to convert an input video (I don't know what the MIME type is) and output it as ogv and mp4 so I can play it on a website. Of course, I'm looking for highest possible quality at the lowest possible file size. I've pieced my commands from what I can find on the net. Am I on the right track? What can I do to improve?

   1. Any ideas how to address the errors I'm getting?

Comment: on the .ogv run ... try dropping : -vcodec, -qscale, -acodec... let ffmpeg infer from your input mime type/ ouput mime type what it should use from list of avail codecs...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not use Windows, therefore I can not give any suggestions for your file name issues.

As for your first question regarding using x264 you are on a good start although I would eliminate `-profile main` it is most likely not required. Also replace `scale="480:-1"` with `scale="trunc(oh*a*2)/2:480"` to prevent an odd sized output; otherwise you may end up with an error: `[libx264] height not divisible by 2`. Basic recommendation for this encoder is to use the highest `-crf` value that gives and acceptable quality and the slowest `-preset` you have patience for. See [FFmpeg: The ultimate Video and Audio Manipulation Tool](http://blog.superuser.com/2012/02/24/ffmpeg-the-ultimate-video-and-audio-manipulation-tool/) and
[FFmpeg and x264 Encoding Guide](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/x264EncodingGuide) for more examples.

The Zeranoe builds do not include support for libfaac. Including it would make the ffmpeg binary non-redistributable. Alternative AAC encoders supported in the Zeranoe builds are `-c:a libvo_aacenc` and the native FFmpeg AAC encoder `-c:a aac -strict experimental`.

An alternative to using libtheora for Theora in ogv is libvpx for VP8 in webm. I have little experience with this encoder so I can not give you any recommendations.

Note that ffmpeg usage questions are better suited for superuser.com.

Answer (score 1):

ogv output from avi input worked fine ...

```
rob@ Videos$ ffmpeg -i ../Downloads/Nikon_Coolpix_S3000.AVI  -f ogg testm.ogv

ffmpeg version git-2012-08-29-85c8303 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Aug 29 2012 08:59:14 with gcc 4.6 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libfaac --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-librtmp --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-version3
  libavutil      51. 70.100 / 51. 70.100
  libavcodec     54. 54.100 / 54. 54.100
  libavformat    54. 25.104 / 54. 25.104
  libavdevice    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.100
  libavfilter     3. 14.100 /  3. 14.100
  libswscale      2.  1.101 /  2.  1.101
  libswresample   0. 15.100 /  0. 15.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
[avi @ 0x2457260] sample size (1) != block align (2)
[avi @ 0x2457260] non-interleaved AVI
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Input #0, avi, from '../Downloads/Nikon_Coolpix_S3000.AVI':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : 
    maker           : NIKON
    model           : COOLPIX S3000
    creation_time   : 2010-11-29 21:32:23
  Duration: 00:00:02.49, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3168 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (MJPG / 0x47504A4D), yuvj422p, 320x240, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 22050 Hz, mono, s16, 352 kb/s
Output #0, ogg, to 'testm.ogv':
  Metadata:
    model           : COOLPIX S3000
    maker           : NIKON
    encoder         : Lavf54.25.104
    Stream #0:0: Video: theora, yuv422p, 320x240, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: flac, 22050 Hz, mono, s16, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg -> libtheora)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le -> flac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   75 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=     134kB time=00:00:02.50 bitrate= 438.3kbits/s    
video:68kB audio:61kB subtitle:0 global headers:3kB muxing overhead 0.925484%
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first use this the error is asking you to replace `-qscale 6` with this `-q:v 6`

For your second, please note that `libfaac` is not supported anymore. Instead use `libvo_aacenc`

Your code should look like this:

```
ffmpeg -i C:/a.avi  -vcodec libx264  -preset slow  -profile main  -crf 20 -c:a libvo_aacenc -b:a 128k  -vf scale="480:-1"   C:/a.mp4
```

Comment: the ffmpeg aac guide https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/AACEncodingGuide shows ``libfdk_aac`` as the recommended encoder.